# Firefox Markdown Viewer Webext : security protection blocks navigation

Tags: firefox, markdown

For some time now, when I open a local markdown file in Firefox, the Markdown Viewer Webext add-on displays this message :

> For your security, Firefox requires you to select local markdown file explicitely before markdown-viewer can open it.
> Select markdown file (or drag it onto this area): [Browse button]

Then, I can open the file with a drag and drop gesture. Annoying, but functional.

If the markdown file has a hyperlink to another local markdown file, it won't open. What is the benefit to be able to link files together if the links can't be used ? That is the way I write a lot of documentation.

Is it possible to disable this stupid security option ?

Platform : Firefox ESR 102.13, Markdown Viewer Webext 2.0.2.8, Ubuntu 22.10